# Where he used the information that $\mu \leq \mu_0$?

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

[image]

This example is from casella_statistical inference book.

Where he used the information that $\mu \leq \mu_0$? 
What if  $\mu \geq \mu_0$?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable in this approach but it appears that the use of $\mu \le \mu_o$ is hidden in the definition of the piecewise function. I imagine if you were instead looking for $\mu \ge \mu_o$ then the piecewise function would be defined differently

Comment: The alternative is $\mu > \mu_0.$ Notice that $\mu_0$ appears in the specification for $\max$ in the numerator. Look carefully at how the LRT is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gone through the problem like this:

The LRT statistic is

\begin{align}
\lambda(\mathbf x)=\frac{\sup\limits_{H_0}L(\mu,\sigma^2\mid \mathbf x)}{\sup\limits_{H_0\cup H_1}L(\mu,\sigma^2\mid \mathbf x)}
&=\frac{\sup\limits_{\mu\le \mu_0,\sigma^2}L(\mu,\sigma^2\mid \mathbf x)}{\sup\limits_{\mu,\sigma^2}L(\mu,\sigma^2\mid \mathbf x)}
\\&=\frac{L\left(\hat{\hat\mu},\hat{\hat\sigma}^2\mid \mathbf x\right)}{L(\hat \mu,\hat\sigma^2\mid \mathbf x)}
\end{align}

, where $(\hat{\hat\mu},\hat{\hat\sigma}^2)$ is the restricted MLE of $(\mu,\sigma^2)$ when $\mu\le \mu_0$ and $(\hat\mu,\hat\sigma^2)$ is the unrestricted MLE of the same. It can be verified that

$$\hat{\hat\mu}=\begin{cases}\hat\mu&,\text{ if }\mu\le \mu_0 \\ \mu_0 &,\text{ if }\mu>\mu_0\end{cases}$$

And that $$\hat{\hat\sigma}^2=\begin{cases} \hat\sigma^2&,\text{ if }\mu\le \mu_0\\ \frac{1}{n}\sum (x_i-\mu_0)^2 &,\text{ if }\mu>\mu_0\end{cases}$$

So the ratio becomes

\begin{align}
\lambda(\mathbf x)&=\begin{cases}1&,\text{ if }\mu\le \mu_0 \\ \\ \frac{L\left(\mu_0,\hat{\hat\sigma}^2\mid \mathbf x\right)}{L(\hat\mu,\hat\sigma^2\mid \mathbf x)}&,\text{ if }\mu>\mu_0\end{cases}
\end{align}

The case $\mu\ge \mu_0$ can be studied in exactly the same manner. For simply $\mu\ne \mu_0$, the ratio $\lambda(\cdot)$ no longer remains a piecewise function.